# How to confugure third Party Lib of Scio Scala API in GCP

Tags: scala, spotify-scio

There is a third party Scio client library which provides a Scala API for Cloud Dataflow in order to access Cloud Bigtable. So, in this Process I am unable to configure Scala API in GCP. Please Help.

Link: https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/third-party-clients

Comment: Please provide example code of what you have tried so far so people can try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Scio is simply a Scala SDK that wraps the Apache Beam Java SDK. There is no "configuration" of Scio in GCP. You simply write a Dataflow job using Scio (Scala) or some combination of Scio and Apache Beam (Scala and Java).

I typically create a Dataflow job with Scio by using the `Giter8` template provided by Spotify. This requires the `sbt` tool. Reference: https://github.com/spotify/scio-template.g8

```sh
>> sbt new spotify/scio-template.g8
```

You'll be prompted for a project name and a package namespace. This automatically creates an `sbt` Scala project. Once the project is set up, you can deploy a pipeline to Dataflow as you would normally execute a compiled Scala binary. The `Giter8` template includes a sample `WordCount` Dataflow job written with Scio.

Scio reference: https://github.com/spotify/scio
sbt reference: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/index.html